# After installing 14.04 LTS 32-Bit, System Locks on "Disk Boot Failure, Insert System Disk and Press Enter"

Tags: system-installation

I am installing 14.04 LTS 32-Bit on an Athlon 700MX with Nvidia graphics card, 10 Gig HD and 2 Gig RAM.  After installing the software all I keep getting is the error above. I have tried GPART, Auto Disk Rebuild, re-mounting.  And it never gets free of the error on the front end.  System boots to installer/trial with any bootable DVD or USB installer.  System set in BIOS to DVD/USB/HDD-1.

What could be the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem could be in corrupted disk. If you can, put the disk in another computer, and check it with `fsck` and for S.M.A.R.T errors

Comment: Also check in your bios if you have the right disk as first boot device selected.

Comment: You don't have to put the disk in other computer. You can use a live CD/DVD with Ubuntu and `gnome-disks` app .

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have something wrong with GRUB or if you used other option with MBR.
I would try to run live CD and see if filesystems are properly mounted
in /etc/fstabs. Also check for /boot/grub/grub.cfg.